# Could not authorize when trying to web deploy with VS2015 to IIS remote agent

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, deployment

I am trying to *Web Deploy* my app via Visual Studio 2015 to a IIS running in the intranet but I always get the following error

> Connected to 192.168.0.20 using the Web Deployment Agent Service, but could not authorize. Make sure you are an administrator on 192.168.0.20

I am using the only local administrator account the remote machine has for the web deploy. On the remote machine (192.168.0.20) there is nothing in the WebDeploy event log about an unauthorised attempt for a web deploy. The logs are completely empty (only 6 error logs days ago)

In terms of troubleshooting, this is the setup I have:

**Remote Machine:**

- Windows 7 Ultimate
- disabled all firewalls
- IIS Express 7.5
- MsDepSvc.exe Process is running
- Added Website (TestWebsite) with application (test) to IIS
- One local administrator account

I followed more or less this turotial for setting the remote machine up:
https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-remote-agent

**Developer Machine:**

- uses the local administrator account

this is the web deploy setting:

```html
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    </SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>http://192.168.0.20</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>TestWebsite/test</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>RemoteAgent</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>False</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>admin</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <PublishDatabaseSettings>
      <Objects xmlns="">
        <ObjectGroup Name="DefaultConnection" Order="1" Enabled="False">
          <Destination Path="" />
          <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
            <Source Path="DBContext" DbContext="TestWebsite.Models.UsersContext, TestWebsite" Origin="Configuration" />
          </Object>
        </ObjectGroup>
      </Objects>
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
    <ADUsesOwinOrOpenIdConnect>False</ADUsesOwinOrOpenIdConnect>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MSDeployParameterValue Include="$(DeployParameterPrefix)DefaultConnection-Web.config Connection String" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I was using a created user (which I called admin) with administrator privileges.
However **the** default administrator account should be used which is disabled by default and can be enabled via:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

Then after giving this account a password those credentials can be used to *web deploy*

Comment: Question still remains, technical  'admin' and 'Administrator' have same administrator privileges. Why web deploy requires only the default administrator account and not admin

Comment: I got the solution at https://forums.iis.net/t/1190239.aspx. It says, you need to add newly created user 'admin' to MSDepSvcUsers user group and it works

Answer (score 0):

I had what appeared to be the same problem. I fixed it by making the 'Web Deployment Agent Service' use the Log on as 'Local System' instead of 'Network Service' in the Services window.

I don't really understand what repercussions this will have besides allowing my admin account to do web deploys, so try at your own risk.

Comment: I dont know if this is relevant but my site uses the full .net 4.6.2 framework with aspcore 1.1.1. I am also using Web Deploy 3.6 on windows server 2016.